# Open UserControl with parameter WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using Galasoft MVVM Light. I'm using one window with multiple `UserControls`, I switch between the `UserControls` with events by changing their `Visibility`. I would like to show a `UserControl` while with passing a parameter to it. It would be easy to pass a parameter if it were using the same `ViewModel` however I have heard this is not good practice.

I can use the `MessengerInstance` to pass the data across the `ViewModels` however this is not an event so the new `ViewModel` doesn't get notified if a message is sent, therefore not knowing when to look for the message.

This is where I instantiate the new View:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ShowDetail, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisConverter}}" Grid.Row="1">
      <View:DetailView/>
</Grid>
```

RelayCommand:

```
OpenDetail= new RelayCommand(() => ShowDetailExecute(), () => true);
```

ICommand property:

```
public ICommand OpenDetail { get; set; }
```

Show Detail Method:

```
    private void ShowDetailExecute()
    {
        ShowMain = false;
        ShowSearch = false;
        ShowDetail = true;
        Header = "Detail";
        var temp = from a in SquirrelDataBase
                   where a.ID == selectedItem.ID && a.Type == selectedItem.Type
                   select a;
        foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            Record = item;
        }
        //MessengerInstance.Send(Record, "Record");
    }
```

ShowDetail Property:

```
    private bool showDetial;

    public bool ShowDetail
    {
        get { return showDetial; }
        set
        {
            showDetial = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ShowDetail");
        }
    }
```

Register Message:

```
MessengerInstance.Register<SquirrelDataGridActiveView>(this, "Record", payload => Record = payload);
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something somewhere is changing the value of ShowDetail, prompting the display of the View. Can you post the code that shows how that happens?

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/323187/MVVMLight-Using-Two-Views
Is this how I should be structuring my View/ViewModels when using multiple 'UserControls'

Comment: Now I'm confused. I was going to suggest putting the Messenger.Send in ShowDetailExecute, but it appears you've already tried that. What's the issue with using the Messenger to pass your value from ShowDetailExecute?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the Detail view is instantiated at the same time as the window, so when does the Detail ViewModel know to look for the message? I even tried binding the Event 'IsVisibilityChanged' through EventToCommand however that didn't work.

Comment: 'when does the Detail ViewModel know to look for the message?' - Have you registered for Messages of the right type in the DetailViewModel? Message registration should happen in the DetailViewModel's constructor: Messenger.Default.Register<MyMessageType>(this, OnMyMessageReceived) .

Comment: Added code in Question above, Should the receiver code automatically run when the code is sent or does the program have to run past the line of code for the message to be received? - I'm asking this because if the receiver doesn't run automatically then the DetailViewModel would have to repeatedly check to see if a message had been sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88084/discussion-between-goobering-and-ryan-searle).